# Excel PowerShell parse data from cell value

Tags: excel, powershell, split

I have a spreadsheet that is an output file from a system and it contains a column of cells that has multiple items separated by a semi-colon. It can look like this:

Cell B4 = "**Group 1; Jackson, Mike J.; Group 3; Group 4**"

I need to extract the user's display name ("Jackson, Mike J.") from the cell. The data can be in any order or it can be more items or just one. Cell data can look like this "Smith, Tom U." or "Group 3; Group 4; Group 5; Group 6; Smith, Tom U.".
I can find the delimiter but I can't seem to split just the user's display name out of the column values.

```
Function Search-Excel {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateScript({
        Try {
            If (Test-Path -Path $_) {$True}
            Else {Throw "$($_) is not a valid path!"}
        }
        Catch {
            Throw $_
        }
    })]
    [string]$Source,
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$SearchText
    #You can specify wildcard characters (*, ?)
)
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
Try {
    $Source = Convert-Path $Source
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Unable locate full path of $($Source)"
    BREAK
}
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Source)
ForEach ($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Sheets)) {
    # Find Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel
    $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText) #What
    If ($Found) {
        # Address Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel
        $BeginAddress = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
        #Initial Found Cell
        $NameOnly = $Found.text.split(';')
        Write-Host $NameOnly
        [pscustomobject]@{
            WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
            Column = $Found.Column
            Row =$Found.Row
            #Text = $Found.Text
            Text = $NameOnly[0]
            Address = $BeginAddress
        }
        Do {
            $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.FindNext($Found)
            $Address = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
            If ($Address -eq $BeginAddress) {
                BREAK
            }
            [pscustomobject]@{
                WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
                Column = $Found.Column
                Row =$Found.Row
                #Text = $Found.Text
                Text = $NameOnly[0]
                Address = $Address
            }                 
        } Until ($False)
    }
    Else {
        Write-Warning "[$($WorkSheet.Name)] Nothing Found!"
    }
}
$workbook.close($false)
[void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$excel)
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Remove-Variable excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} 
$Source = 'C:\Scripts\PS\Excel\MOCK_DATA_Users_Email_Gender_IP_Address.xlsx'
$SearchText = ","
$Delimiter = ";"
$NameOnly = $null
Search-Excel -Source $Source -SearchText $SearchText | Format-Table
```